# Someone help me setting up a react-toolbox project with scss support, redux-devtools, hotmodule replacement?

Tags: reactjs, sass, webpack-2, mern, react-toolbox

I am trying to set up MERN project. I need below configuration

- `react-toolbox` as UI library
- `scss` and `css` for styling
- hot module replacement
- redux devtools for development

Is there any boilerplate which is having this setup?
If not please someone create or tweak these existing repo's and set it for me?

- https://github.com/theajr/react-redux-webpack2-boilerplate.git or
- https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox.git

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [boilerplate](https://github.com/Venugopal46/react-toolbox-boilerplate).

- webpack configuration

  1. Hot reloading and Redux devtools in dev mode
  2. manifest, vendor and app code separation in production mode
- react-toolbox
- redux-saga (you can remove if you don't want this)